# What is an open and enclosed parking area?

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference

What is an open and enclosed parking area?

Could anybody please break these two terms up for me? I've searched online, but still couldn't find a clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

"Open" and "enclosed" describe two different kinds of *parking garages* (US) or *multistorey car parks* (UK).

From [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multistorey_car_park#Nomenclature) (emphases in original):

> United States building codes use the term **open parking garage** to refer to a structure designed for car storage that has openings along at least 40% of the perimeter, as opposed to an **enclosed parking garage** that requires mechanical ventilation.

An open parking garage is very obvious. It *looks* like a parking garage:
[image: open parking garage, CC BY-SA 3.0 license, attribution at https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hradec_Kr%C3%A1lov%C3%A9,_Resslova,_parkovac%C3%AD_d%C5%AFm.jpg]

An enclosed parking garage will look more like an ordinary building from the outside. The lower levels of a high-rise or skyscraper may be taken up by an enclosed parking garage, with "real" floors above:

[image: skyscrapers with enclosed parking garage, CC BY 3.0 license, attribution at https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Met_2_Miami_20110307.jpg]

---

Photos taken from Wikipedia/Wikimedia. [First photo](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hradec_Kr%C3%A1lov%C3%A9,_Resslova,_parkovac%C3%AD_d%C5%AFm.jpg) by [ŠJů](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedista:%C5%A0J%C5%AF) under the [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en) license, [second photo](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Met_2_Miami_20110307.jpg) by [Averette](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Averette) under the [CC BY 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/deed.en) license.

Comment: Thanks for breaking it up for me!